Neovim | gopher.vim | GoAddTag | Struct not found
I have recently migrated from Vim to NeoVim. There were many configuration distros like NVChad, LazyVim, LunarVim etc but the issue was the steep keymap learning curve
So I started building a custom version with minimal programming oriented configuration. Most of it is done but GoAddTag is not working somehow. Here is how it can be tested
This is the repository
TazVim Link
With Neovim install run below. Please do check README.md
git clone https://github.com/tahseenjamal/tazvim.git $HOME/.config/nvim

Then write a simple golang program like below
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func (p Person) Greet() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello, my name is %s and I am %d years old.\n", p.Name, p.Age)
}

func main() {
    p := Person{Name: "Alice", Age: 30}
    p.Greet()
}

With this program open in the neovim, if you open command, which is shift + :
> GoTagAdd json

I see the error
gopher.nim
struct not found

I tried a lot but cannot understand what is the issue. If someone can use my neovim configuration and help and tell.

After a bit of further work I realised that the cursor has to be under the Struct name
In above case it should be under any of the characters of
Person

And then when you shift + : and type
GoTagAdd json

it worked!!!
